# Issue in applying zoom with 'transform: scale()' a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I applied zoom property with `transform` the container or `div` which I applied the zoom entirely shrinks or enlarges. My objective is to fix the parent div as a view window and apply the zoom to the inner elements of the div.

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="panzoom">
    <div class="diagram">
      <div id="i0"  class="item">Root!</div>
      <div id="i1" class="item">Child 1</div>
      <div  id="i11" class="item">Child 1.1</div>
      <div  id="i12" class="item">Child 1.2</div>
      <div id="i2" class="item">Child 2</div>
      <div id="i21" class="item">Child 2.1</div>
      <div id="i3" class="item">Child 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to fix `panzoom` as viewing window and zoom the `diagram` so that the draggable items inside the diagram can dragged the entire view window (`panzoom`).

Comment: Stupid question: Why not just apply it to `panzoom` instead?

Comment: Is this css `transform`? you should include the css part in the question.

Comment: when applying it to 'panzoom' the div entirely transforms, I need inner elements to scale and panzoom must be fixed in the position

Comment: I used `transform: scale(1.5);` for css

Comment: https://imagebin.ca/v/4ZLr6HJEld0y
when applied to pan zoom